# Terraform State File in storage account

Tags: azure, azure-storage-account

We have Terraform state file stored in the Azure Storage Account. In case storage account went down we will be screwed. What is the best way to store the file? where?

Comment: Hello @Zara , can you please clarify "In case storage account went down we will be screwed"? and please add more details like the storage account type you are using etc.

Comment: Thanks for getting back @AnsumanBal-MT.

Standard general-purpose and LRS

Comment: ohkay .. so if you are using LRS then its locally replicated .. so you can use GRS or ZRS which will replicate data in 2 zones or locations . so if your data is lost from primary there will be a backup in secondary location. you can refer this document : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-redundancy?toc=/azure/storage/blobs/toc.json

Comment: if i understand correctly then you are talking about accidental deletes or availibility of storage account and if thats the case then please go through the above link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, there are two methods to store a terraform state file i.e. Locally in your machine or in a Storage account in azure .

> In case storage account went down we will be screwed. What is the best
> way to store the file? where?

As confirmed , You are using `Standard_LRS` which is not preferred as per the [Microsoft Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-redundancy?toc=/azure/storage/blobs/toc.json#redundancy-in-the-primary-region) if you are looking for high availability.

> Locally redundant storage (LRS) copies your data synchronously three
> times within a single physical location in the primary region. LRS is
> the least expensive replication option, but is not recommended for
> applications requiring high availability or durability.

So, as a solution you can change the storage account type as per your requirement to `Standard_GRS` or `Standard_ZRS` so that your data is present in two locations i.e. replicated.

[image]

[image]

You can change it by going to your storage account>>Configuration>>replication as shown below:

[image]

If You want more details on Disaster recovery (if one location is down) or data protection from Accidental Deletes then please refer the below documents:

[Disaster recovery and storage account failover - Azure Storage | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-disaster-recovery-guidance?toc=/azure/storage/blobs/toc.json)

[Soft delete for containers - Azure Storage | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/soft-delete-container-overview)